# ubuntu upgrade 14 to 16 NOT 18

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Is there a simple way to `do-release-upgrade` from 14 -> 16 and not from 14 -> 18? The default behavior of `do-release-upgrade` is from 14 (trusty) to 18 (bionic) directly. This is giving me trouble and is also not my intention. There are no resources that I have found to specify update version.

I would prefer not to just do clean install, as I have files in /opt/ and /etc/ that I would like to keep.

Comment: You can try upgrading using disk image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade from 14.04 LTS or 15.10 to 16.04 from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760347/how-to-upgrade-from-14-04-lts-or-15-10-to-16-04-from-terminal) (you should backup current system, then disable all third-party repositories and change *trusty* to *xenial* in all your sources.list files).